# How can I use ImageFormatConverter.ConvertFromString to convert a string containing HTML response to an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, image, visual-studio-2008

This is what I achieved:

### in pageload

```
{
    panelmain.Controls.Add(abc);
    panelmain.Controls.Add(grid1);
    string toexport;
    toexport = RenderControl(panelmain);

    ImageFormatConverter imgc = new ImageFormatConverter();
    System.Drawing.Image convertedimage;
    convertedimage = (System.Drawing.Image) imgc.ConvertFromString(toexport);
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=tm.jpeg");
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    Response.Write(convertedimage);
    Response.End();
    //form1.Controls.Add(abc);
}

public string RenderControl(Control ctrl)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Write(sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The error is:

> ImageFormatConverter cannot convert from System.String.

Comment: panelmain is a Panel control?  You're trying to create an Image from the rendered html?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? How do you expect a string to be converted to an image?

Comment: Related?  [Render HTML as an Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image)

Comment: please close this and refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594544/how-to-convert-response-stream-to-an-image-revised   i except the string to convert as its basically html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have misinterpreted the documentation of `ConvertFromString` here, explanation:

You are using an [`ImageformatConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageformatconverter.aspx) class which inherits and overrides [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx). This means that `ConvertFromString` is inherited from the superclass, but because there's no way you can convert a string to an image (unless you have a vivid imagination), this method always returns null (according to documentation), or throws a `NotSupportedException`. This is the default behavior of the base class and an overriding class can define custom behavior, which in your case, [has not been done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25ds5cb6.aspx).

To convert from a string you will first have to define what you want. I.e., is the string a path to an image? Is it a piece of text and you want to render an image from that? Is it a Base64 encoded string that contains an image? Is it a rendered HTML page or does it contain an RTF document? Once you have an answer to these questions, you can choose the correct converter or image constructor.

EDIT: because your question seems to be about rendering HTML as an image, check out [this post at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image), as also mentioned by [rchern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181481/rchern) above.

Comment: thanku please have a look at other question i post with great detail, and the above solution doesnot work, it say magic code goes here? but whats the code!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594544/how-to-convert-response-stream-to-an-image-revised

Comment: @user287745: I have repeated there what I said here and added a bit more detail on how you can interpret the answers in the link that I posted here.