# How to convert response stream to an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, html-to-jpeg

Please note this link [Render HTML as an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image) is not helpful.

In previously asked question answered said they don't get what I want to do exactly so here's is the full code also.

I simply want that instead of a TABLES I rendered an image (of the content) on the page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel panelmain = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel();
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal abc = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal();
    abc.Text = "as<br/>dasdas<br/>dasdad";


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt;
    DataRow dr;
    DataColumn idCoulumn;
    DataColumn nameCoulumn;

    dt = new DataTable();
    idCoulumn = new DataColumn("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    nameCoulumn = new DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add(idCoulumn);
    dt.Columns.Add(nameCoulumn);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = 1;
    dr["Name"] = "Name1";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = 2;
    dr["Name"] = "Name2";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grid1 = new 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
    grid1.DataSource = ds;
    grid1.DataBind();

    panelmain.Controls.Add(abc);
    panelmain.Controls.Add(grid1);

    string toexport;
    toexport = RenderControl(panelmain);

    Byte[] bitmapData = new Byte[100000];
    bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(toexport));
    System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);
    Bitmap bitImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));

    Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=tm.gif");
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    Response.Write(bitImage);
    Response.End();

    }



public string FixBase64ForImage(string Image)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(Image, Image.Length);

    sbText.Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);

    sbText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

    return sbText.ToString();
}



public string RenderControl(Control ctrl)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Write(sb);

    return sb.ToString();



}
```

Comment: Well, for one, your code is entirely missing the part where you load an HTML rendering engine and use that to render the content.

Comment: public string RenderControl(Control ctrl) this does the work, its able to produce a doc file using thos returned string,. please please help.. what am i missing give links

Comment: It doesn't produce "a doc file", it just produces HTML. Rendering HTML to an image is a very daunting task. Just look at how complicated web browsers are.

Comment: @user287745: user @Matti is correct, `public string RenderControl(Control ctrl)` does not create a *picture* of HTML, it creates an in-memory string of *HTML code*. Creating an image of that means rendering the HTML code using one of the many browsers, capturing it as a screenshot and then use that image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render HTML as an Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594239/how-can-i-use-imageformatconverter-convertfromstring-to-convert-a-string-containi/3594313#3594313) you already received an answer (by me), referring [to another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image) where this question was answered. The second answer in that thread links to another page on the web where the whole process of starting a `WebBrowser` object, rending a page, capturing the image, converting that to your preferred image file format, saving it locally is explained. Not a straightforward task (expect to spend some hours), but not too hard either.

To repeat [the answer in the referred to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image/339232#339232), just have a look at this [WinCustomize.com article](http://www.wincustomize.com/article/136426), download the source and experiment