# Good way to check if file extension is of an image or not

Tags: c#, file-extension, openfiledialog, filefilter

I have this file types Filters:

```
    public const string Png = "PNG Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|" + "*.png";
    public const string Jpg = "JPEG File Interchange Format (*.jpg *.jpeg *jfif)|" + "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif";
    public const string Bmp = "BMP Windows Bitmap (*.bmp)|" + "*.bmp";
    public const string Tif = "TIF Tagged Imaged File Format (*.tif *.tiff)|" + "*.tif;*.tiff";
    public const string Gif = "GIF Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif)|" + "*.gif";
    public const string AllImages = "Image file|" + "*.png; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jfif; *.bmp;*.tif; *.tiff; *.gif";
    public const string AllFiles = "All files (*.*)" + "|*.*";

    static FilesFilters()
    {
        imagesTypes = new List<string>();
        imagesTypes.Add(Png);
        imagesTypes.Add(Jpg);
        imagesTypes.Add(Bmp);
        imagesTypes.Add(Tif);
        imagesTypes.Add(Gif);
   }
```

OBS: Is there any default filters in .NET or a free library for that?

**I need a static method that checks if a string is an image or not.** How would you solve this?

```
    //ext == Path.GetExtension(yourpath)
    public static bool IsImageExtension(string ext)
    {
        return (ext == ".bmp" || .... etc etc...)
    }
```

Solution using Jeroen Vannevel EndsWith. I think it is ok.

```
    public static bool IsImageExtension(string ext)
    {
        return imagesTypes.Contains(ext);
    }
```

Comment: You might also want to consider doing it by [detecting the MIME Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300567/alternative-to-findmimefromdata-method-in-urlmon-dll-one-which-has-more-mime-typ), its more "trust worthy" that file extension,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `.endsWith(ext)`. It's not a very secure method though: I could rename 'bla.jpg' to 'bla.png' and it would still be a jpg file.

```
public static bool HasImageExtension(this string source){
 return (source.EndsWith(".png") || source.EndsWith(".jpg"));
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337750/get-imageformat-from-file-extension) provides a more secure solution:

```
string InputSource = "mypic.png";
System.Drawing.Image imgInput = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(InputSource);
Graphics gInput = Graphics.fromimage(imgInput);
Imaging.ImageFormat thisFormat = imgInput.rawformat;
```

Comment: "I could rename 'bla.jpg' to 'bla.png' and it would still be a jpg file" Yeah I know that, but this leads to another problem... I think I will leave with this because all images will be loaded as a Bitmap object. endsWith is nice.

Comment: If you have a list of allowed imagetypes just use `return imageTypes.Contains(ext);` in accordance to @Alejandro's example.

Comment: Opsss! Thank you!! By the way: is there any default filters in .NET or a free library for that?

Comment: Not that I know off, but I haven't done any search for it either.

Comment: does this secure solution 100% safe? can we use it to save images as we want? I mean we can save gInput  as png for example right? and it would be safe?

Comment: @DaveLucre If you desperately want to change the code to account for lowercase then you should use the `.EndsWith` overload with a StringComparison argument. `ToLower()` for string comparison is not done.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel since you so desperately want to suppress any solution suggested by others, perhaps you can follow your own advice and implement the suggested solution yourself.

Answer (score 17):

```
private static readonly string[] _validExtensions = {"jpg","bmp","gif","png"}; //  etc

public static bool IsImageExtension(string ext)
{
    return _validExtensions.Contains(ext.ToLower());
}
```

If you want to be able to make the list configurable at runtime without recompiling, add something like:

```
private static string[] _validExtensions;

private static string[] ValidExtensions()
{
    if(_validExtensions==null)
    { 
        // load from app.config, text file, DB, wherever
    }
    return _validExtensions
}

public static bool IsImageExtension(string ext)
{
    return ValidExtensions().Contains(ext.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: Make sure you include `using System.Linq;` to get access to the `Contains` extension method.

Comment: Note that this will only work with all lowercase extensions -- remember that Windows's file system is case insensitive, but C#'s string comparison is not. It's not uncommon for extensions to be all caps, e.g., somefile.PNG. [This overload of Contains can fix this limitation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) For example, use `ValidExtensions().Contains(ext, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`, note that you need `using System.Linq;` to take advantage of that `Contains` overload.

Comment: @daniellmb nitpicking: Technically you don't need LINQ for [List.Contains(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx), but you do need LINQ for [Enumerable.Contains(this IEnumerable<T>,T, Comparer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx), the latter extension method overload would help resolve some issues in the code in this post.

Answer (score 5):

An option would be to have a list of all possible valid image extensions, then that method would only check if the supplied extension is within that collection:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> validExtensions = new HashSet<string>()
{
    "png",
    "jpg",
    "bmp"
    // Other possible extensions
};
```

Then in the validation you just check against that:

```
public static bool IsImageExtension(string ext)
{
    return validExtensions.Contains(ext);
}
```

Comment: Good extra info is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558754/define-what-is-a-hashset

Comment: Note that this will only work with all lowercase extensions -- remember that Windows's file system is case insensitive, but C#'s string comparison (by default) is not. It's not uncommon for extensions to be all caps, e.g., somefile.PNG. Consider adding `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to your `HashSet` as Oliver did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21835675/4975230).

Answer (score 5):

This method automatically creates a filter for the `OpenFileDialog`. It uses the informations of the image decoders supported by Windows. It also adds information of "unknown" image formats (see `default` case of the `switch` statement).

```
private static string SupportedImageDecodersFilter()
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

    string allExtensions = encoders
        .Select(enc => enc.FilenameExtension)
        .Aggregate((current, next) => current + ";" + next)
        .ToLowerInvariant();
    var sb = new StringBuilder(500)
        .AppendFormat("Image files  ({0})|{1}", allExtensions.Replace(";", ", "),
                      allExtensions);
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo encoder in encoders) {
        string ext = encoder.FilenameExtension.ToLowerInvariant();
        // ext = "*.bmp;*.dib;*.rle"           descr = BMP
        // ext = "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif"   descr = JPEG
        // ext = "*.gif"                       descr = GIF
        // ext = "*.tif;*.tiff"                descr = TIFF
        // ext = "*.png"                       descr = PNG

        string caption;
        switch (encoder.FormatDescription) {
            case "BMP":
                caption = "Windows Bitmap";
                break;
            case "JPEG":
                caption = "JPEG file";
                break;
            case "GIF":
                caption = "Graphics Interchange Format";
                break;
            case "TIFF":
                caption = "Tagged Image File Format";
                break;
            case "PNG":
                caption = "Portable Network Graphics";
                break;
            default:
                caption = encoder.FormatDescription;
                break;
        }
        sb.AppendFormat("|{0}  ({1})|{2}", caption, ext.Replace(";", ", "), ext);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var dlg = new OpenFileDialog {
    Filter = SupportedImageDecodersFilter(),
    Multiselect = false,
    Title = "Choose Image"
};
```

---

The code above (slightly modified) can be used to find available image file extensions. In order to test if a given file extension denotes an image, I would put the valid extension in a `HashSet`. HashSets have an
O(1) access time! Make sure to choose a case insensitive string comparer. Since the file extensions do not contain accented or non Latin letters, the culture can safely be ignored. Therefore I use an ordinal string comparison.

```
var imageExtensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
imageExtensions.Add(".png");
imageExtensions.Add(".bmp");
...
```

And test if a filename is an image:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
bool isImage = imageExtensions.Contains(extension);
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had to do something similiar. Here is my solution:

```
    private bool IsImage(string fileExtension)
    {
        return GetImageFileExtensions().Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()));
    }

    private static List<string> GetImageFileExtensions()
    {
        return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                             .Select(c => c.FilenameExtension)
                             .SelectMany(e => e.Split(';'))
                             .Select(e => e.Replace("*", "").ToLower())
                             .ToList();            
    }
```

Comment: This adds a dependency to System.Drawing.Imaging which is not cross platform. Doesn't work in .Net Standard / Core.