# Creating valid file extension list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm applying a function to specific file formats

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
if (extension == ".txt")
{
    DoSomething(files[i]);
}
```

But I have too many file extension, not only txt. What is the basic way to create a white list and check if it's included on that list?

Comment: This seems similar to this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17736237/2557263

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a white list and check if extension is inside it or not

```
var whitelist = new[]
{
    ".txt", ".bat", ".con"
};

string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
if (whitelist.Contains(extension))
{
    DoSomething(files[i]);
}
```

if your white list size becomes large ([more than 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance)) try using [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) for better performance

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<string> fileExtensions = new List<string>();
                      fileExtensions.AddRange(".txt,.png,.bmp,.pdf".Split(','));
                      string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
                      if (fileExtensions.Contains(extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                      {
                        //  DoSomething(files[i]);
                      }
```